# how to reverse query set for m2m relation in Django and check if object exists

Tags: python, django, m2m

I need to check if an object exists in a reversed m2m Django relation.

**Models**

```py
class PlayerProfile(models.Model):
    """
    Player profile for every user -
   تحديد شكل كل لاعب خاص بكل مستخدم
    """
    is_cap = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    app_user = models.ForeignKey("users.AppUser", on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="player_profile_list_for_app_user")
    t_shirt_size = models.ForeignKey(TShirtSize, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position)
    average_skill = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region,on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    """
    Stores Available teams 
    """
    name = models.ForeignKey(TeamName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="team_set_for_name",
                             verbose_name=_("Team Name"), help_text=("Name of the team"))
    home_strip = models.ForeignKey(TeamStrip, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="team_set_for_home_teamstrip",
                                   verbose_name=_(
                                       "Team Home Strip"), help_text=("Home Shirt for the team"))
    away_strip = models.ForeignKey(TeamStrip, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="team_set_for_away_teamstrip",
                                   verbose_name=_(
                                       "Team Away Strip"), help_text=("Away Shirt for the team"))
    league = models.ForeignKey("leagues.LeagueSeason", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="team_set_for_league",
                               null=True, verbose_name=_("League Seasson"),
                               help_text=_("League seasson that team plays in "))
    cap = models.ForeignKey("players.PlayerProfile", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name="team_set_for_cap_playerprofile",
                            verbose_name=_("Team Captain"), help_text=_("Captain of the team"))
    players = models.ManyToManyField("players.PlayerProfile", blank=True, verbose_name=_(
        "Team Players"), help_text=_("Players that is playing in the team"), related_name="team_set_for_players")
    average_skill = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,
                                        default=0, verbose_name=_(
            "Average Team Skill"), help_text=_("An Average of Player's skills"))
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=_("Team Points"),
                                         help_text=_("Team points in the current league season"))
```

Now the case that I have a `Team` Object and I need to queryset on `PlayerProfile` to return only `playerProfile` that belongs to that `Team` Objects based on the field `

Here is what I have tried to do :

```py
PlayerProfile.objects.filter(Q(team=away_team_object) | Q(
                team=home_team_object) | Q(id=home_team_object.cap.id) | Q(id=away_team_object.cap.id))
```

But it gets me this error :

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'team' into field. Choices are: app_user, app_user_id, average_skill, card_set_for_playerprofile, created, goal_assist, goal_maker, id, is_cap, joinrequest_set_for_playerprofile, leagueseason, positions, region, region_id, skill, t_shirt_size, t_shirt_size_id, team_set_for_cap_playerprofile, team_set_for_players
```

Comment: Use `team_set_for_players` instead of `team`? Since that was the related name you have set

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that you have a **team** object, just use

```
team.players.all()
```

to get the **PlayerProfiles** of that team